# More precise values with optim and fitdistr

Tags: r, optimization

I want to have more precise values with optim.

Consider the following variable:

```
test<-c(1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,0.5,0.4,-0.1)
```

Now, I want to fit a normal density, estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are:

```
mean(test) 

[1] 1.345455
sd(test)
[1] 0.9223488
```

Or I can use

```
library(MASS)
fitdistr(test,"normal")
```

and I get

```
    mean         sd    
  1.3454545   0.8794251 
 (0.2651566) (0.1874941)
```

Which is not exactly the same, why? Now I want to do this manually with optim:

```
loglikenorm<-function(theta){
return (-sum(log(dnorm(test,mean=theta[1],sd=theta[2])))
}
optim(c(0,0.01),loglikenorm)
```

and I get

```
$par
[1] 1.3451582 0.8798248
```

which is not exact. I want to have it more exact, how can I do this?

I have a case, where fitdistr and optim in the same setting as here (with normal distr) lead to slightly different estimates, so how can I do optim more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question (about difference in `sd` results) is [**the difference between `sample` and `population` estimates**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance).

The `sample` estimate of `sd` is given by:

```
sqrt(1/(N-1) * sigma((x - xbar)^2))
```

Whereas, the population estimate of `sd` is given by:

```
sqrt(1/N * sigma((x - xbar)^2))
```

The R function `sd` computes by default the `sample` estimate where as the MASS package function, the population estimate. If you're trying to estimate the population parameters from your sample (as a representative sample), then you should be using population variance/sd.

```
# sample estimate
sqrt(1/10 * sum((test - mean(test))^2))
# [1] 0.9223488

# population estimate
sqrt(1/11 * sum((test - mean(test))^2))
# [1] 0.8794251
```

With the optimise function, I get:

```
> optim(c(0,0.1),loglikenorm)
# $par
# [1] 1.3458745 0.8795433

0.8795433 - 0.8794251 
# [1] 0.0001182
```

Given your sample size of 11, this is an acceptable error threshold I think..

Comment: @SimonO101, I think you should "undelete" your answer. It explains the difference in the algorithm between `optimise` and `fitdistr` iiuc..?